# Windows 10 installation freeze when 64 bit is selected

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, 64-bit, freeze

I'm trying to install a 64bit version of Windows 10 on my old laptop. It's got 2nd generation i5 cpu.

I created multiple USB drives using the official media creation tool, RUFUS with different settings (uefi, legacy bios, mbr, gpt, fat32, ntfs etc etc), but every time I select 64bit, it goes to the windows logo screen and as soon as the circling dots appear it freezes right away. I waited hours, nothing happens. Whereas if I select 32bit,it installs perfectly.

I know it accepts 64bit because intel website said so and I did try to install a Windows 7 64 bit and it did work. I also tried to upgrade from W7 to W10 but the same thing happens!

The only thing I can think off is to update the BIOS but unfortunately it's an unbranded laptop and I don't want to risk installing bios updates for it that I find on the Internet.

Any other ideas?

Comment: First, the Windows Media Creations Tool is usually *most* reliable. Second, check required BIOS/UEFI settings, e.g. Secure Boot probably should be *enabled*. Also, the only generally accepted format for USB flash boot devices is FAT32. Others likely will *not* work. Check if RAM is sufficient, too.

Comment: Sounds like a case where while the processor is 64-bit the UEFI kernel is 32-bit. A 2nd i5 laptop would have been most likely installed with Windows 8. If it came with Windows 7 then UEFI kernel most definitely is 32-bit.  This essentially means a 64-bit edition of Windows cannot be installed in UEFI mode

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes, I tried with fat32 first as that was the default. There is no secure boot in the bios. The bios is very simple. RAM is 4gb.

Comment: @Ramhound but is it the same with windows 7? Because I installed a 64bit with windows 7. So what can I do then? What is your advice that I should do? I don't have much knowledge of OS's and BIOS etc

Comment: Windows Visa and above were NOT licensed separately for 32-bit and 64-bit. Windows 7 doesn’t even support secure boot. The processor requirements for Windows 7 and Windows 10 (regardless if your running 32-bit or 64-bit) are different. Windows 7 didn’t support booting into a 64-bit install if the UEFI kernel was 32-bit.  Your hardware is old enough where that likely is the case